# how to get row id of all the rows of a updatable dynamic browse widget in progress 4gl?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

how to get row id of all the rows of a updatable dynamic browse widget in progress 4gl?

I tried the rowid() function but it is only returning the rowid of first row.
Is there any possibility that I can do it using buffer-handle?

Answer (score 3):

The browse widget navigates the query. The query fetches records in a buffer and the buffer returns the ROWID.

If you're looking for selected records, the browse widget has a GET-SELECTED-RECORD(i) method, that positions the query and so the buffer to the given selected record.

If you want all records in the browse, you need to loop through the query using

GET FIRST/NEXT {&QUERY-NAME} NO-LOCK.

and enquire the ROWID for each record. But this will be costly when there are lots of records.